# Can't get ether from Rinkeby testnet faucet

Tags: testnets

I'm a new user trying out the Rinkeby testnet. I followed the procedure in this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wKFz5c3TU4s).  But I can't get ether. [This page](https://faucet.rinkeby.io/) says "Invalid User... boom!"

I've contacted GitHub. They suspect that it's due to misbehaving spam-detecting robots, so they just unflagged my account "twice" but still doesn't work. What should I do?

Comment: You can try other testnets too! Rinkeby is the most popular and used testnet!

Comment: You need to post your ethereum address in which you want ethers to googlee+, fb or twitter. And instead of address, paste the link to your post (that contains your address) in the faucet page.

Answer (score 5):

To get ether from the Rinkeby testnet, you have to post your ethereum address to one of the following social networks:

1. Twitter (public)
2. Google+ (public)
3. Facebook (public)

Once you've made the post, copy the public post URL and paste it into the Rinkeby testnet faucet. You'll get your test ether quickly after that.

Comment: this works in 2021!

Answer (score 1):

Reddit is the best way that works consistently https://www.reddit.com/r/ethdev/comments/61zdn8/if_you_need_some_ropsten_testnet_ethers/

Answer (score 1):

There many faucets for ropsten network that you can use without login in facebook or other social network.

http://faucet.ropsten.be:3001/
https://faucet.metamask.io/

These two work immediately.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED: Make your tweet public, in this way Rinkeby can validate.  https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-make-twitter-public#targetText=When%20your%20Twitter%20account%20is,to%20make%20your%20account%20public.

Answer (score 1):

It seem to be very late but will post my finding so that if anyone searching for the solution can get the answer

The ETH address we are posting in tweet is not incorrect format and can give error invalid checksum
like -- 0xc00e94cb662c3520282e6f5717214004a7f26888

To make it valid just open https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xc00e94cb662c3520282e6f5717214004a7f26888

Copy the address from website and the tweet that address

You will receive rinkeby ETH

Hopefully this will help

Answer (score 0):

We have created a universal faucet [here](https://faucets.blockxlabs.com/?utm_source=stackexchange) It is just a captcha for validation so it should be easier to use.